# Can't install mongodb on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I can't install mongodb on Ubuntu. Apparently there is a default version installed already.

I cannot remove either and default version doesn't work.

```
$ mongo                            
MongoDB shell version v5.0.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status mongod          
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-05-19 15:56:04 PDT; 4min 49s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 3060686 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=217/USER)
   Main PID: 3060686 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

May 19 15:56:04 racknerd-2c3196 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
May 19 15:56:04 racknerd-2c3196 systemd[3060686]: mongod.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
May 19 15:56:04 racknerd-2c3196 systemd[3060686]: mongod.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/mongod: No such process
May 19 15:56:04 racknerd-2c3196 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
May 19 15:56:04 racknerd-2c3196 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Try `mongod --repair`. If it doesn't work, try restarting. If it fails with lock error, remove lock and restart daemon.

Comment: Your **installation** was successful, you installed latest version 5.0.8. However, you cannot start your database. Have a look at mongod logfile, see `systemLog.path` setting in config file `/etc/mongod.conf` - typically logfile is `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: I cannot uninstall because i think i have ppa and default ubuntu versions installed.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`

This works in bash (for zsh use `sudo apt-get purge 'mongodb-org*'`